# Sort an Array and letting empty slots be last

Tags: c#

I am trying to sort my array after removal of information for a index spot.
For example:
The user removes index 1 of an array of 5 items and replace the information in index 1 with "".

Now i want the index to sort the index so that the index 1 (with the "" as data) gets to the last part. 
For this i use Array.Sort()but as i understand and noticed it will place the "" index first in the array but i want that part last. 
To try and tackle this i have tried the following code:

```
    static string[] Sort(string[] array, ref int counter)
    {
        Array.Sort(array);
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == "")
            {

                if (i + 1 < array.Length)
                {
                    string temporary = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temporary;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

But it will not add the "" first in the list.
Please advice!

Comment: Why not use a List?

Answer (score 2):

Another option to sort in-place is to use a custom `Comparer`:

```
string[] array = { "2", "", "1" };

Array.Sort(array, (a, b) => a == "" ? 1 : b == "" ? -1 : a.CompareTo(b));   // "1", "2", ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var sorted = stringArray.OrderBy(x => x.Length ==0).ThenBy(x=>x);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using your method, something like this would work:

```
static string[] Sort(string[] array, ref int counter)
{
    Array.Sort(array);
    int lowestFilled = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != "")
        {
            if (i - lowestFilled > 1)
            {
                string tmp = array[lowestFilled + 1];
                array[lowestFilled + 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
                ++lowestFilled;
            }
        }
        if (array[i] != "")
        {
            lowestFilled = i;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

I would recommend going with ainwood's option, however.